# How to find the product is going to be displayed under upsell list or not?

Tags: magento2, up-sells, callback

I have been added `Callback` button and "Contact Number" to products by overriding the `price template`. While displaying the price of a product, how to check whether that particular product is going to be displayed under `upsell` list or not?

> (Don't want to display the callback button for `Upsell` products. Only
>   the contact number should be displayed)

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the product is upsell or not using following way:

```
protected $_product;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
) {
    $this->_product = $product;
}

public function isUpsellProduct($sku) {
    $collection = $this->_product->getUpSellProductCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('sku', ['eq' => 'NewArrivals-5']);

    if (!empty($collection->getData())) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope it may help you!